# Need knowledge on facebook API data retrieve

Tags: facebook

I want to know, wether can I get the Facebook Page Insight Data using FB app. I am newbie and want to get data of Facebook page of registered users.

All the data as well as engagement of all post on that page.

Comment: Go read the documentation on Insights, then you will see what metrics are available.

Answer (score -1):

For this you have to learn about the graph API of facebook, but for scraping the data from page you can start by reading [this](http://minimaxir.com/2015/07/facebook-scraper/).